# Is it possible to programmatically post on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, api, posting

Here my primary use case would be doing something like writing up a post in vim from a terminal (putting a title, tags as appropriate) and then sending it through a bash function that posts to Stack Overflow.

Is doing something like this possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible. All the spammers do it all the time.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, with the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/). The [documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) home page lists all available methods.

Answer (score 4):

> [post] through a bash function that posts to Stack Overflow.
>
> Is doing something like this possible?

Everything is possible, but in this case I'd refrain from it.

When you post a question, you're [supposed to keep looking at it for at least a couple of minutes, so you can watch for comments, edits and perhaps even answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> **Post the question and respond to feedback**
>
> After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!

So sure, you could post a question through the API or any other means, but know that you're going to have to open your browser afterwards anyway to monitor said question.

Comment: There are ways through the API to be notified of any activity on your question, so I'm not convinced that you're "supposed" to look at it for a couple of minutes.  It wouldn't hurt, but there's no hard-and-fast rule for it.

Comment: @Makoto if someone is going to write a fully functional application using the API, then that's fine. I doubt that will be feasible through a batch script. Also, I now included the text from the "how-to-ask" page stating you _are_ supposed to keep looking at your question.

Answer (score -11):

Yes using this hook

> wp_insert_post()

Comment: This is [meta], the site about Stack Overflow and the software that powers it. This question is not about WordPress.